# FFmpeg rotate and scale image overlay on video

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I have been able to rotate image which  overlays on video on android using this comand

```
String[] complexCommand2 = {"-y", "-i", videoFilePath, "-i", imagepath, "-filter_complex","[1:v] rotate=30*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih) [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay=40:10",  "-codec:a","copy", outputFilePath};
```

However I want to also scale the image how can that be done

Answer (score 0):

To scale after the rotate:  (just replaced  and  with desired values.

`-filter_complex "[1:v] rotate=30*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih) [rotate];[rotate]scale=<scale_width>:<scale_height>[scale];[0:v][scale] overlay=40:10[out]" -map [out] .......`

to scale before the rotate: (just replaced  and  with desired values.

`-filter_complex "[1:v]scale=<scale_width>:<scale_height>[scale];[scale]rotate=30*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(iw):oh=roth(ih) [rotate];[0:v][rotate] overlay=40:10[out]" -map [out] .......`

Comment: i got it working using this command `String[] complexCommand2 = {"-y", "-i", videoFilePath, "-i", imagepath, "-filter_complex","[1:v] rotate=30*PI/180:c=none:ow=rotw(30*PI/180):oh=roth(30*PI/180) [rotate];[rotate]scale=50:50[scale];[0:v][scale] overlay=40:10","-codec:a","copy", outputFilePath};` but now there is black background for the image which rotated how can we solve that